# Non-breaking space not working in Overleaf

Tags: line-breaking, white-space

I am trying to insert a non-breaking space because one of the lines in my text ends with an `a`, namely `introduces the problem and proposes ~a (cont. in the next line)`. However, the tilde operator does nothing, using `\,` is futile as well. How to fix this?

Comment: No space between proposes and ~a; proposes~a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should type

```
introduces the problem and proposes~a (cont.\ in the next line)
```

instead.